# 3D Plot Surface With Custom Data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Sample data like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,4,10)
y = np.linspace(3,4,10)
z = np.linspace(10,20,7)
data = np.random.rand(10,7)
```

and custom plot like this:

```
xx = np.ones((10,7))
yy = np.ones((10,7))
zz = np.ones((10,7))
for i in range(7):
    xx[:,i] = x
    yy[:,i] = y
for i in range(10):
    zz[i,:] = z
```

And wireframe like this :

[image]

When I try this to get surface color:

```
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx,yy,zz,facecolor = cm.coolwarm(data))
plt.show()
```

Error like this :

> ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4

I can't figure out why this is fail. I need this custom plot to replace Meshgrid (truly need this plot as my output). Can anyone solve this problem? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colors= cm.coolwarm(data)`
`ax.plot_surface(xx,yy,zz,cmap = cm.coolwarm, facecolors =colors)`

You can read more about this at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is running well. But I don't understand why we need to stack colormap and facecolors at the same time?.

Comment: The plot_surface function does not have a "facecolor" parameter, but there is a "facecolors" parameter. Colormap is not necessary in this case.